# Reducing verbosity of logging with seleniumwire and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, logging, seleniumwire

I have an issue where I'm unable to control the verbosity of logs in parts of my Python scripts - it's probably somehow related to either `selenium` or `seleniumwire`. I have a main python file `run.py` which is used to initiate other python scripts.

My goal was to launch scripts from `run.py` and log everything under one main log file, ideally called `run.log` and then separate log files which contain all the logs for the other scripts that are launched by `run.py`, e.g. `other_script` would have it's own log file called `other_script.log`. Essentially logs related to `other_script` would be found in both files, but `run.py` would have logs about other scripts as well.

The way I have this set up currently is that I have a function `setup_logging` that is initiated under `run.py`:

```
def setup_logging(python_file_name: str = None):
    if python_file_name:
        python_file_names = [python_file_name]
    else:
        python_file_names = ['run', 'other_script', 'other_script_2']
    for python_file_name in python_file_names:
        log_file = os.path.join(os.env['GOOGLE_DRIVE_PATH'], 'logs', f'{python_file_name}.log')
        file_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_file, when='W0', interval=1)
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s - %(message)s')
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(file_handler)

def main():
    setup_logging()
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    # do stuff
    logger.info('Running other_script')
    os.system('python3 other_script.py')
```

Then in `other_script.py`

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def main():
    driver = get_webdriver()
    driver.get('www.some_url.com')
    request = driver.wait_for_request('/data?')
    logger.info(f'Request successful for {url}')
    for request in driver.requests:
        json_response = get_json(request)
        logger.debug(f'Logging info about this request {json_response}')
        # etc...
```

So my logger is set to level INFO which I want to keep as is, because there are a lot of print statements I wish to keep. What happens is that all the logs end up in `__main__.log` and the last part (`other_script.py`) creates a lot of verbose logs under INFO stemming presumably from selenium/seleniumwire.

Example of verbose logs I want removed

```
2024-01-21 21:02:21,758 - INFO - request - Capturing request: https://www.long-url.com/...
2024-01-21 21:02:21,784 - INFO - response - Capturing response: https://www.long-url.com/... 200
```

I have tried the following

- in `setup_logging` change the log level to `WARNING`, but now I don't get any of the `INFO`-level print statements I actually want to see in the logs (e.g. `logger.info(f'Request successful for {url}')`) .
- set `--log-level 2` or above under `chrome_options` for the webdriver
- in `other_script.py` try to specify a different logging level for `selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection` with this

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER as seleniumLogger
seleniumLogger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
# Set the threshold for urllib3 to WARNING
from urllib3.connectionpool import log as urllibLogger
urllibLogger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```